# alpha function in Octave not yet implemented

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to reproduce the really cool plot from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278788/plotting-3d-in-matlab/). You can run the code on my [Saturn Fiddle](https://saturnapi.com/vpartition/glqcunknyqlp9acq9). I'm getting the error

> alpha not yet implemented in Octave

How can achieve the transparency in Octave to reproduce the same plot? Thanks!

```
% Code adapted from @rayryeng
% https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278788/plotting-3d-in-matlab/

vert = [0 1 0; 1 0 0; 0 0 1];
patch('Vertices', vert, 'Faces', 1:3, 'FaceColor', 'cyan')
view(3)
set(gca, 'xdir', 'reverse')
set(gca, 'ydir', 'reverse')
grid
% alpha('color') %%Not yet implemented in Octave :(
[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:(1/6):1);
Z = 1 - X - Y;
Z(Z < -0.01) = NaN;
hold on;
plot3(X, Y, Z, 'b.', 'MarkerSize', 32);
text(0.3,0.3,0.4, 'NE');
line([1/2 1/3], [1/2 1/3], [0 1/3], 'color', 'black');
xlabel('R'); ylabel('P'); zlabel('S');
print("MyPNG.png", "-dpng", "-r60")
```

Comment: Please post the actual plotting code you're using.  There may well be a different library ( gnuplot, perhaps, using OpenGL) that will support transparency.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft added my code

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072412/setting-transparancy-of-surface-plot-on-octave